# Merge similar rows and count

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My sample database query result looks like this.

```
ID  Product Owner
1   iPhone  Shanu
2   MotoX   Shajan
3   HTC     Amal
4   iPhone  Jibi
5   MotoX   Anil
6   iPhone  Gregary
```

I like to get the number of each phones
I want the result like this:

```
iPhone  3
MotoX   2
HTC     1
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly basic query -

```
SELECT `product`, count(`product`)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `product`;
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard OP can only "accept" ;-)

Comment: Oh, yeah....I forgot that ;-) Thanks @Fred-ii-